# experiencing an error while connecting to server

Tags: express, mongoose, mongodb-query, backend

when i start my backend program, it shows following errors in the terminal

`MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\e 23\cinebaba\cinebaba-backend\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:202:26) at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\e 23\cinebaba\cinebaba-backend\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:61:60) at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28) at processIncomingData (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\e 23\cinebaba\cinebaba-backend\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:124:16) at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\e 23\cinebaba\cinebaba-backend\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9) at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12) at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10) at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10) at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28) { ok: 0, code: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError', connectionGeneration: 0, [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' } }`

this is my code for the app;

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const movie = require('./models/movie')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const port = 3000

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/movies', async (req, res) => {
  const movies= await movie.find()
  res.status(200).json(movies)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://janakripan:<i replaced the original password here>@cluster0.aapjgni.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
}
```

i'm also unable to send any request through postman.
please resolve the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: double check your credentials first and I recommend you use API testing tools like postman to check if you can connect with that url.

Comment: Loos like you are using the wrong authentication credentials. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#std-label-special-pass-characters) for possible problems. In my experience it's either special characters used in the password or wrong/no authentication database used.

Comment: Thank you. That was the exact problem. Thanks for pointing out that